# Can I take a timelapse on a Gopro Hero 5?

Tags: timelapse, gopro, time

Does the Gopro Hero 5 have a self timer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demonstrates a total lack of research by the O.P. A simple google search for "GoPro Hero 5 features" should probably be sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelClark should i delete this post?

Comment: @Zangar Probably, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can swipe in from the right to select shoot modes.  Timelapse is an option and you can even select how often it shoots a frame.

https://www.camerajabber.com/shoot-time-lapse-video-gopro-hero5-black/